# Magento modules

Tags: module, magento2.2.6, third-party-module

We have installed some of the third party plugins on our Magento site. But, when I check the module status using the below command, It showing many of the modules which start from Magento_xxx that we don't installed manually.

> php bin/magento module:status

Please see the below screenshot:

[image]

Please help me to understand what those modules are and where it comes from.

Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: in magento 2 app/etc/config.php you can see the list of modules installed

Comment: No worry, they are just Magento Core files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide a great eCommerce solution with many great pre-built features, Magento has created its own modules.

When you run the following command:

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

**Magento shows the list of all modules with the respective status of the modules, even if it is a third party module or its own module.**

All modules of Magento core start with **`Magento_`**. Apart from that, Magento time to time includes custom popular functionalities in the newer versions. For example Amazon Pay etc. When such third party solutions become part of Magento, they also become in the list of modules. These modules can be found under **`/vendor/<module_package>`**, for example **`/vendor/amzn`**, **`/vendor/dotmailer`** etc.

In a nutshell, don't worry about the modules in the list you have not installed. These may be part of default Magento functionality.

To be sure, you can match it with the default Magento with the same version.

I hope it should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the code directory into app and then create or put your modules.

With Magento2, in general, the directory is not mandatory.

Modueles are palced into vendor (because the use of Composer) and probably you will install your 3rd-party modules using Composer (in one way or another).

Only if you need to create a custom module without composer support you will use the /app/code directory.

Is the same than Magento 1 with /app/code/local. The local pool isn't present and you can create it if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

**please use this link for help :**

https://marketplace.magento.com/media/catalog/product/pozzito-pozzito-module-livechat-100-0-2-ce/user_guides.pdf